# Is it bluejacking attack or bluesnarfing attack?

Tags: wireless-networking

If unknown device is trying to pair with my device through bluetooth, is it bluejacking attack or bluesnarfing attack?

Comment: It may just be Bluejacking because they Requested to connect if they were bluesnarfing they would probably be on your device already from what I understand. Ive been Researching this lately.

Answer (score 2):

[Bluejacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluejacking) is the sending of unsolicited messages over Bluetooth to Bluetooth-enabled devices.  [Bluejacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluejacking) is the sending of either a picture or a message from one user to an unsuspecting user through Bluetooth wireless technology.

[Bluesnarfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluesnarfing) is the unauthorized access of information from a wireless device through a Bluetooth connection.  This allows access to a calendar, contact list, emails and text messages, and on some phones, users can copy pictures and private videos.

> If unknown device is trying to pair with my device through bluetooth,
>   is it bluejacking attack or bluesnarfing attack?

A device attempting to pair with another device, would be unable to send unsolicited messages to another device, so it could not be bluejacking.  A device attempting to pair with another device also would be unable to access information on that other device.  In other words, what you describe, is neither a bluejacking or bluesnarfing attack.